# I have this working php code but it doesn't return the expected resuts

Tags: php

I have PHP code retrieving data from MySQL DB. What I want is to press a button then a popup must display data for that relevant `id` or display data on that `id` row. So for the first btn it works well but on other btn's it displays data from btn 1.

Is there any solution out there?
Thanks

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users"
$results = mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
$chck_res = mysqli_num_rows($results);

if ($chck_res > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name =$row['name'];
        $lastName = $row['lName'];

        ?>
            <div class="container">
                <button onClick="popWin()">View data at <?php echo $id; ></button>
            </div>

            <div id="popup">
                echo $id = $row['id'];
                echo $name =$row['name'];
                echo $lastName = $row['lName'];
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
#popup {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
function popWin() {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "Block";
}
```

Comment: **HTML element attribute ID must be unique**. Use **class** instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has errors. you

1. did not terminate the select query
2. did not end php tag on echo id on line 14

   ```
   <?php
   $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
   $results = mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
   $chck_res = mysqli_num_rows($results);

   if ($chck_res > 0) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
   $id = $row['id'];
   $name =$row['name'];
   $lastName = $row['lName'];

   ?>
       <div class="container">
           <button onClick="popWin()">View data at <?php echo $id; ?></button>
       </div>

       <div id="popup">
              <?php echo  $id = $row['id'];
              echo $name =$row['name'];
              echo $lastName = $row['lName'];?>
       </div>
   <?php   }}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

DOM elements **must have unique ID**, you can't get access to the second element with the same ID via `getElementById`.

Try to replace your divs with next:

```
 <div>
        <div class="container">
            <button onClick="popWin(this)">View data at <?php echo $id; ></button>
        </div>

        <div class="popup">
          <?= $id = $row['id']; ?>
          <?= $name = $row['name']; ?>
          <?= $lastName = $row['lName']; ?>
       </div>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
function popWin(btn) {
     btn.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].style.display = "Block";
     console.log(btn.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].innerHTML);
}
```

```js
function popWin(btn) {
    btn.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].style.display = "Block"; 
    console.log(btn.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <button onClick="popWin(this)">View data at 2</button>
    </div>

    <div class="popup">
        name id 2
   </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <button onClick="popWin(this)">View data at 1</button>
    </div>

    <div class="popup">
        name id 1
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Hope, you're welcome. If it's not so hard for you, please, accept answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. Thank u once more